Celery flower - basic authentication not working
I would like to add basic authentication to flower UI via the --basic-auth="usr:pasw" option. My expectation is that the user would first have to access the /login endpoint to authenticate before being authorized for other endpoints (e.g. listing the tasks).
When I try that and start the app at endpoint / I get "Access denied" as expected. Then I try to access the /login endpoint but I get the exception
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:5555', method='GET', uri='/login', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\local\poetry\cache\virtualenvs\myapp-hXApG96V-py3.9\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1786, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "D:\local\poetry\cache\virtualenvs\myapp-hXApG96V-py3.9\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
    yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
  File "D:\local\poetry\cache\virtualenvs\myapp-hXApG96V-py3.9\lib\site-packages\flower\views\auth.py", line 42, in get
    redirect_uri = self.settings[self._OAUTH_SETTINGS_KEY]['redirect_uri']
KeyError: 'oauth'
Uncaught exception in write_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\local\poetry\cache\virtualenvs\myapp-hXApG96V-py3.9\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1786, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "D:\local\poetry\cache\virtualenvs\myapp-hXApG96V-py3.9\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
    yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
  File "D:\local\poetry\cache\virtualenvs\myapp-hXApG96V-py3.9\lib\site-packages\flower\views\auth.py", line 42, in get
    redirect_uri = self.settings[self._OAUTH_SETTINGS_KEY]['redirect_uri']
KeyError: 'oauth'

It's for some reason defaulting to Oauth - which I don't want to use.
EDIT
I digged a bit deeper. Flower declares the tornado request handler BasicHandler which checks if the Authorization header on the request is present and if the header matches the --basic-auth credentials that were set when starting flower. This auth mechanism works fine for me. However when I access the views in my browser I don't have an easy way to set this Authorization header. It would be better if there was a form on the UI where I can enter username and password.
